# Table columns with display:flex are misaligned

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've created a table and for whatever(important) reason (because i dont know how many cells in a row are coming from back end and thats why i cant use colspan for that, can be one row with 2 cells and second one with 4 for example) i need to use flexbox for that.
But the problem occurs when text in one cell is longer - then all layout ia broken

[image]

How can i fix that?

I've applied:

```
tr {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
}

td {
display: flex;
width: 100%;
}
```

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Flexbox does not align columns in a bigger context (table). You can use display: table-row and display: table-column as an alternative

Comment: Thanks for providing your CSS, but can you please provide the relevant HTML as well? It's rather difficult to answer this question without it. It would help if you could update your question to list all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: if you are using table, which is best for this kind of layout...I don't understand why are you using `flex` in `tr`..?

Comment: We can't debug an image, we need a working code snippet to be able to provide a proper answer. Also, when you say that you don't know what comes back from back end, the only sane solution is to use a script.

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that your `td` tags have a `display:  flex;` property but not a `flex` value set.

When the `flex` property is not defined, each will take the most space they can while not wrapping.

Use the next CSS:

```
td {
  flex:  1;  
}
```

I would suggest that for longer fields, you use a higher `flex` value (ex. `flex: 4`), and for shorter fields, a lower `flex` value (ex. `flex: 1`).

I am attaching a codepen that has the desired behaviour.

https://codepen.io/elujambio/pen/WMXjjL

When you don't have a value for said cell, just use an `td` containing an `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score -2):

You can override overflow behavior by setting min-width of cell:

```
td {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
}
```